# JSF-Ajax issue on populating ArrayList

Tags: java, ajax, jsf, jsf-2, ajax4jsf

I wrote a `JSF` page that is supposed help the client select items to add in a list (an ArrayList). I use Ajax for the operation to be effected when the value of the selectonemenu is changed.

When the application runs there is no exception, and when the Ajax is triggered the operation is effected. However it doesn't seem to be persisted. In other words each time the operation is launched it does add the object to the list, but at the next launch the List is reset to 0 and only newly added object is in it.

My code:

Bean:

```
//Assume all necessary imports have been made
public class MBean
{
  private List<SomethingElse> objects;
  private List<SomethingElse> toFill;

  public MBean()
  {
         toFill = new ArrayList();
         //Let's assume that the list is correctly created and populated in here
  }

  public void addObjectToList(AjaxBehaviorEvent event)
  {
      try
      {
          SomethingElse obj = (SomethingElse) event.getNewValue();
          toFill.add(obj);
      }
      catch(Exception e)
      {
          e.printStackTrace();
      }
  }

  public List<SomethingElse> getObjects()
  {
         return objects;
  }

  public void setObjects(List<SomethingElse> objects)
  {
         this.objects = objects;
  }
}
```

JSF:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
  xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
  xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich"
  xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j">
<h:head>
<title>AJAX or SELECTONEMENU ISSUE</title>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <f:view encoding="utf-8">
            <section>

                        <h:form id="testForm">
                            <h:dataTable id="showTb" value="#{mBean.toFill}"
                                         var="det" cellpadding="5px" rows="0">
                                <f:facet name="header">
                                    Added objects
                                </f:facet>
                                <h:column>
                                    <h:outputText value="#{det}"/>
                                </h:column>
                            </h:dataTable><br/>

                            <a4j:region>
                            <h:selectOneMenu converter="#{aConverter}">      
<!-- Assume converter is working-->
                                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Object to add" itemValue=""/>
                                <f:selectItems value="#{mBean.objects}" var="o"/>
                            </h:selectOneMenu><br/>
                            <h:commandLink value="Add">
                                <a4j:ajax event="click" execute="@region" 
listener="#{mBean.addObjectToList}" render="showTb"/>
                            </h:commandLink>
                            </a4j:region>

                            <br/><br/>
                        </h:form>

                        </section>
      </f:view>
</h:body>
</html>
```

How can i fix it?

Comment: What is the scope of your managed bean ?

Comment: Session scoped it is!

Comment: Try to render it `@ViewScoped`.

Comment: What's with the Session scope? I used it with some other Ajax operations that work fine. This one is the only failure.

Comment: What do you mean by next launch ?

Answer (score 0):

did you try using `a4j:commandLink` instead of `a4j:ajax` nested in `h:commandLink`?

since the click event of `h:commandLink` itself is not blocked with something like `onclick="return false;"`, it seems to be clearing the list by refreshing the page.